# overload dereference (!) and assignment (:=) operators in f#

Tags: f#, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload the dereference (!) and assignment (:=) operators but not globally. I still want to keep the usual ref op overloads.  Here's some code to illustrate the issues:

```
type MyVar<'a>(init:'a) =
    let mutable _value = init
    member __.Get() = _value
    member __.Set x = _value <- x
    //static member (!) (s:MyVar<'a>) = s.Get()      // compiles, doesn't work
    //static member (:=) (d:MyVar<'a>, s) = d.Set(s) // warning, doesn't work

//let inline (!) (x :MyVar<'a>) = x.Get()           // overrides !ref
//let inline (:=) (x :MyVar<'a>) (v :'a) = x.Set(v) // overrides ref := v 
let inline (!!) (x :MyVar<'a>) = x.Get()            // works but ugly
let inline (.=) (x :MyVar<'a>) (v :'a) = x.Set(v)   // works ... meh

let test_myvar() =
    let mv = new MyVar<_>("wee")
    let r = ref 100
    let x = !mv
    let y = !!mv
    let z = !r
    mv .= "haaa"
    r := 42
```

**Solution:**

@Carsten's solution is what I was looking for & works.  However, it turns out that I am using Websharper which compiles using Quotations and @Carstens solution becomes a little [more complex](https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper.ui.next/blob/master/WebSharper.UI.Next/Notation.fs).  Since Websharper.UI.Next includes that solution, all I had to was include in my project, and it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get this to work with [*static constraints*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) - by overloading the `(!)` and `(:=)` operators as you tried:

```
type MyVar<'a>(init:'a) =
    let mutable _value = init
    member __.Value with get () = _value and set v = _value <- v

let inline (!) a =
    (^a : (member Value : ^b) a)

let inline (:=) a v =
    (^a : (member Value : ^b with set) (a, v))
```

I removed your accessors because I only need the same as `Ref<'a>` has (but you can re-add them)

#### Demonstration

Here is an F#-interactive session demonstrating this with your values:

```
val mv : MyVar<string>
val r : int ref = {contents = 100;}

> !mv;;
val it : string = "wee"
> !r;;
val it : int = 100
> mv := "It works";;
val it : unit = ()
> !mv;;
val it : string = "It works"
> r := 50;;
val it : unit = ()
> !r;;
val it : int = 50
```

---

**remark**

I'm not sure if I would really do this though - you only reinvent the `Ref`-cell (as an class) and gain nothing and of course it might be hard to read for others - so treat with care.

Comment: This is useful if MyRef has other features, for example we use this in UI.Next for [reactive variables](https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper.ui.next/blob/master/WebSharper.UI.Next/Notation.fsi).

Comment: That's what I was looking for. But there was some complications.  See OP.

Comment: I get your remark now.  I could just use Value as in mv.Value <- mv.Value + 1, instead of the mv := !mv + 1 ... hmmm.